# how to properly edit hosts, hostname and resolf.conf?

Tags: linux, hostname, hosts

I have been searching the Internet for a real nop tutorial on the subject but could not found any direct info. on how to edit these files the proper way.

I have a Debian Internet server that I use to host some personal domains and runs Squid and rTorrent. The server is up and running with no problems.  However, I am confused about a few things.

Lets say that I named my server (foo), my domain is (example.com) and my public IP is 95.211.133.200 now:

1. should /etc/hostname contains:

   ```
   tango.example.com
   ```

   or

   ```
   tango <----- just the server name
   ```
2. should `/etc/hosts` contain:

   ```
   127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain   localhost
   95.211.133.200  foo.example.com         foo
   ```
3. should `/etc/resolf.conf` contain (along with the name servers) both:

   ```
   domain example.com
   search example.com
   ```

   or just the first one.

   Are there any other files that I should edit in order to make things right?
4. last thing, the command:

   ```
   domainname

   returns: (none)
   ```

   I believe it should return (example.com). What should I do to correct that?

Comment: Your shift key appears to be broken.

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like a homework assignment I once had. Anyway, all of these questions can be answered in man pages: `resolv.conf(5)`, `hostname(1)` and `hosts(5)`

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/hostname` should have just `foo`

`/etc/hosts` looks fine

`/etc/resolv.conf` should probably be `example.com` for both, depending on your use case.  Note that you named it `/etc/resolf.conf` and it should be `v` and not `f`

I don't know about `domainname`